# scanning for rowkeys between start and end time

Tags: hbase

I have a hbase table where the rowkey pattern is {id1},{id2},{millisec}, I need to get all the rowkeys between start and end millisec keeping either id1 or id2 constant, how do i accomplish in hbase ? I am using a java client.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**a. For a known {id1}**

You have to perform a scan and provide the start & stop rows. Take a look at this example extracted from the [HBase reference guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book/data_model_operations.html):

```
public static final byte[] CF = "cf".getBytes();
public static final byte[] ATTR = "attr".getBytes();
...

HTable htable = ...      // instantiate HTable

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(CF, ATTR);
scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes("row")); // start key is inclusive
scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes("rox"));  // stop key is exclusive
ResultScanner rs = htable.getScanner(scan);
try {
  for (Result r = rs.next(); r != null; r = rs.next()) {
  // process result...
} finally {
  rs.close();  // always close the ResultScanner!
}
```

Additionally, you can use `setTimeRange(long minStamp, long maxStamp)` to discard rows based on the timestamp.

**b. For a known {id2}**

The only way to avoid a full table scan is to implement a secondary index (I'm not up to date about this), or go for the classic data redundancy and store the same data also as {id2},{id1},{millisec} (depending on your needs you can avoid some data), which acts as a secondary index.

In case you cannot afford any of the above, you'll have to scan the whole table. To speed up the scan you can:

1. Use `setTimeRange(long minStamp, long maxStamp)`.
2. Use a [custom filter](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter.html#filterRowKey%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) with a `filterRowKey(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)` method to ignore further processing of unwanted rows (every row which doesn't have the {id2} or if the timestamp is not within the range).
3. Use the FuzzyRowFilter proposed [here](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/08/09/consider-using-fuzzyrowfilter-when-in-need-for-secondary-indexes-in-hbase/)

The best approach depends on your needs and data, I'll go for implementing a custom filter which could give you a decent performance given the fixed width of your row keys. If it's not enough, I'll go for data redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For doing a scan (without full table scan) I require the knowledge of start and stop row which must be present in the table, since this is time series data and contains millisec, how do i determine start and end keys , or scan doesnt mandate the start and stop keys to be present in the table ?

Comment: That's the catch, start and stop keys are not required to be present, they're just boundaries. You can use the id1 key as starting point and the id1+1 as stop point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Scan](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html)

The setTimeRange method can be a good fit for what you're looking for.

```
public Scan setTimeRange(long minStamp,
                long maxStamp)
                  throws IOException
Get versions of columns only within the specified timestamp range, [minStamp, maxStamp). Note, default maximum versions to return is 1. If your time range spans more than one version and you want all versions returned, up the number of versions beyond the defaut.
Parameters:
minStamp - minimum timestamp value, inclusive
maxStamp - maximum timestamp value, exclusive
Returns:
this
Throws:
IOException - if invalid time range
```