# Hbase scan by key using java

Tags: java, hbase

I'm trying to scan an Hbase table

```
Scan scanrt = new Scan();
scanrt.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes("~"+Key+"|"));
scanrt.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes("|"+Key+"~"));
ResultScanner scannerrt = null;
try {
    scannerrt = tablert.getScanner(scanrt);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It doesn't work because the element I try to scan is not the first one in the row, Is there any solution I put this "~" but I think that we can only use it in the end not the begining of a row.

The structure  of the row is : date,element1,element2,key....

Comment: Your Q is not clear. You scan HBase by *rows*, not columns. You can't scan "inside" in a row with a `Scan` object.

Comment: yes question is bit un clear. However check this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/20888109/647053